# How to set Format for DateTimePicker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker

In my application I'm using the DateTimePicker control from the Xceed Wpf toolkit.

I would like to set the format so that only the hours and minutes can be edited, I want to remove the calendar. since I'm using DateTimePicker to establish how long a process takes. Like this 3d print, it took 20h 40m and save it in my database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eryCi.png) only this part

Answer (score 0):

To set the format of the Xceed DateTimePicker control to only show hours and minutes, you can set the Format property to "HH:mm". This will display the time in hours and minutes, and only the time portion can be edited.

Example:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Format="HH:mm" />
```

This will format the control to only show and allow editing of the hour and minute values.

Comment: it works, but when I press the right button it shows the calendar, do you know if that button can be removed?